# setxkbmap conflicting with xmodmap

Tags: keyboard, keyboard-layout, xmodmap, keyboard-event

So initially I had the following in my ~/.Xmodmap which mapped CapsLock+HJKL to left/down/up/right like in vim:

```
keycode 66 = Mode_switch
keysym h = h H Left
keysym j = j J Down
keysym k = k K Up
keysym l = l L Right
```

Everything worked just fine until I finally figured out how to get multi-language support working:

```
setxkbmap -option 'grp:rctrl_rshift_toggle' -layout us,fr,pt -variant ,azerty,mac
```

Now it's a little messed up: The CapsLock+HJKL only work in `us` mode, but not in `fr` (french) or `pt` (portuguese).

In fact, with `fr` mode, it's all reversed: HJKL act as up/down/etc and CapsLock+hjkl show the actual key values.

In `pt` it's different again...

I just want consistent vim-like navigation using CapsLock as the meta key throughout all languages.

(I know there's a `caps:hyper` option in `setxkbmap` and I'm happy to use that if anyone has a solution along that path.)

Note that I'm using Ubuntu 18.10 with i3 as my desktop.

Comment: Tip - if you want to reset all changes made by setxkbmap and xmodmap, use the command "$ setxkbmap -option".

Answer (score 1):

`setxkbmap` not only alters the alphanumeric keys to the values given in the map; it also resets all other keys to the startup default.

If you have assigned values to <kbd>CapsLock</kbd> + <kbd>H</kbd><kbd>J</kbd><kbd>K</kbd><kbd>L</kbd> keys, these settings may be lost.

For further information, look at: [Configuring keyboards](http://wiki.linuxquestions.org/wiki/Configuring_keyboards)